Is this restricted variant of predicate logic decidable, but expressive enough to be encoded by STLC ($\lambda \to$)?
As in the question, is it the case that a predicate calculus with these properties is decidable?

n-ary predicates
quantifiers
finite domain of discourse
impredicativity disallowed
no function terms

If so, is it possible to encode the semantics of this logic in Simply Typed Lambda Calculus ($\lambda\to$)?

@KijeongLim The derivation rules of $\lambda\to$ can be defined in terms of function symbols, but not the logic itself.



If the domain of discourse is decidable -- i.e., we can decide whether two given elements are the same -- and your assumptions are satisfied then the object language is decidable.


Is the result you want to prove there exists a translation function $| \cdot |$ such that, for all sentences $\varphi$ of the object language, $$ \models \varphi \iff \mathbf{STLC} \vdash | \varphi | ? $$



@KijeongLim 1. My worry is something like Trakhtenbrot's theorem will pose an issue for the restricted predicate calculus. 2. We already know that $\lambda P$ can encode a minimal predicate logic. I am wondering the same is possible with STLC for the restricted predicate calculus.
